# PERL parallel multi threading

Tags: multithreading, perl

I am writing a PERL script involving multithreading. It has a GUI and the number of threads to be used will be taken as user input. Depending on this number, the script should generate threads which all access the same sub. I want the n threads to work in parallel. But when I create a loop, the parallel processing is lost. Any idea as to how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Post some code that exhibits this problem.

Comment: You generally will want to start off all your threads and remember each one you created in a list. Then later iterate through the list if you want to wait for them all to finish. You may need to yield. You may have other problems or you may be spawning your threads wrongly. We need an example

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the simplest way to answer would be to recommend you to look at something like [POE](http://poe.perl.org/). The framework cookbook webpage provides many examples that surely will be a good starting point for your original issue.

Depending on your GUI platform, you may also want to spend time on event loops provided by the framework itself.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to call threads->yield() function occasionally in the processing loops.  The yield() function gives a "hint" to give up the CPU for a thread.